# How to include double quotes in shell if we execute in python

Tags: python, powershell, shell

Am using python to execute shell script i  need to include double quotes on this
My code :

```
os.system(" -p '" +conf.value+"'")
```

i need to take single quotes and add double quotes in this
Conf.value is a variable read from json file

Comment: So something like `os.system(f"-p '\"{conf.value}\"'")`?

Answer (score 0):

`string = f""" -p "{value}" """`

In the case of double quotes surrounding a variable:

`os.system(f""" -p "{conf.value}" """)`

> `-p "$conf.value"`

or, single quotes surrounding double quotes, surrounding a variable:

`os.system(f""" -p '"{conf.value}"' """)`

> `-p '"$conf.value"'`